# dealloc is not being triggered when dismissViewControllerAnimated is called

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, uiviewcontroller, dealloc

I am working in a Non-Arc application and i have a memory problem. When i call  dismissViewControllerAnimated to close a UIViewController function.. Dealloc is not being called to release the view memory which is retained instead.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is something keeping a strong reference to the controller?

Comment: Like what for example .. i don't use strong type.. only retain

Comment: Retain is like strong.

Comment: Retain implies __strong ownership (composition in OOP terms). Do you remember to use `release`? If not, then you might place `[self release]` in `dismissViewControllerAnimated`'s completion block.

Comment: The real question is, why is it non-ARC?